# How to find the scsi_host_template functions for a block device?

Tags: c, linux, linux-kernel, linux-device-driver, scsi

I was looking into the IO path of the Linux kernel, and towards the bottom in the function `scsi_dispatch_cmd()`, the driver code is invoked

```
rtn = host->hostt->queuecommand(host, cmd);
```

So, for my block device like `/dev/sda/`, is there a way to find out which `hostt` or `scsi_host_template` it is using. I want to check which function `queuecommand` is pointing to..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just as a sketch of reflection on this subject.
In my machine for USB drive I can see this:

```
$ ls -l /dev/sdg
brw-rw---- 1 root disk 8, 96 Apr 27 01:21 /dev/sdg
$ ll /sys/dev/block/8\:96/device/drive
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 0 Apr 27 01:32 /sys/dev/block/8:96/device/driver -> ../../../../../../../../../bus/scsi/drivers/sd
```

So normally such block devices are handled through the regular [Linux scsi disk driver](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v4.9.220/source/drivers/scsi/sd.c). Which is related with e.g. usb handling:

```
$ lsmod | grep sd
sd_mod                 49152  13
scsi_mod              225280  5 sd_mod,usb_storage,libata,uas,sg
```

In this particular case we can see the relation between queuecommand and mentioned drive:

```
$ grep queuecommand /proc/kallsyms
ffffffffc052be60 t uas_queuecommand [uas]
ffffffffc0582ad0 t queuecommand [usb_storage]
```

Now, being in Linux source dir:

```
$ grep -rnI '\.queuecommand =' | grep usb
drivers/usb/storage/uas.c:846:  .queuecommand = uas_queuecommand,
drivers/usb/storage/scsiglue.c:609: .queuecommand =         queuecommand,
```

Hope this will help you.